# Trying to get time difference with milliseconds in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have a column in mysql that is a `varchar` and has data like this: `02:18,1` or `02:18,10` or `02:18,325`. in that column named `timpPS` data repesents: `minutes:seconds,milisec`.
the values are times obtained by some competitors and i want to display in a php the time diference from the best time (smallest) so i need to do the mysql interogation but i got stuck.
What i want is to find the smallest value in that column and from the same column to substrat the smallest value.
i tryed:

```
SELECT timpPS, 
(str_to_date( TimpPS, '%i:%s,%f' )) AS Timp,
(SELECT min( str_to_date( TimpPS, '%i:%s,%f' )) FROM timpi ) AS minim,
(str_to_date( concat("00:",TimpPS), '%H:%i:%s,%f' ) - (SELECT min( str_to_date( concat("00:",TimpPS), '%H:%i:%s,%f' )) FROM timpi )) AS Diff 
FROM
    timpi 
ORDER BY
    Diff ASC;
```

Please help

some data:

```
| TimpPS | minim | Diff |
| ------ | ----- | ---- |
| 02:16,0 | 00:02:16.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 02:18,1 | 00:02:16.000000 | 2.100000 |
| 02:19,0 | 00:02:16.000000 | 3.000000 |
| 02:20,0 | 00:02:16.000000 | 4.000000 |
| 03:16,0 | 00:02:16.000000 | 100.000000 |
| 05:55,0 | 00:02:16.000000 | 339.000000 |
| 05:55,0 | 00:02:16.000000 | 339.000000 |
```

TimPS exist in mysql table,
minim values in that column is obtained by using `(SELECT min( str_to_date( TimpPS, '%i:%s,%f' )) FROM timpi ) AS minim` = 02:16,0
`Diff` shoud be the results but if difference is more than 1 min i do not get the corect results.

Thank you for pointing me to corect direction:

This is the corect mysql sentence:

```
SELECT timpPS, 
(str_to_date( TimpPS, '%i:%s,%f' )) AS Timp,
(SELECT min( str_to_date( TimpPS, '%i:%s,%f' )) FROM timpi ) AS minim,
TIMEDIFF(str_to_date( TimpPS, '%i:%s,%f' ),(SELECT min( str_to_date( TimpPS, '%i:%s,%f' )) FROM timpi )) AS Diff 
FROM
    timpi 
ORDER BY
    Diff ASC;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results, as tabular text, would help clarifying your question.

Comment: `TimePS | Difference
02:16,0 | 0.000000
02:18,1 | 2.100000
02:19,0 | 3.000000
02:20,0 | 4.000000
05:55,0 | 339.000000
05:55,0 | 339.000000
06:30,0 | 414.000000
07:08,0 | 492.000000
`
Where TimePS is allready in database in a table named timpi,
`Select min( str_to_date( TimpPS, '%i:%s,%f' )) FROM timpi = 00:02:16.000000`
but Difference i get is not correct when is more than 1 min, so i think conversion is wrong

Comment: Thanks @Topo_AS, but please add the information directly in your question (you can [edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76508524/edit)). Comments have very limited formatting options.

Comment: i put some example in the main question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a time in a math operation, it is cast to a number, so 02:16 becomes 216; you can't meaningfully subtract such numbers.

Use timediff instead of subtracting; if you need a number of seconds, then call time_to_sec on the timediff result.